# Call a variable in a reactive in a R Shiny APP

Tags: r, shiny

I have download a database through a R shiny App and I can't call any variables into my next reactive. My error is the object was not found. 
I have separated the server from the UI part and I have one app by tabname.

Comment: Hello Claire, this question can be much better if you would share some code so we can replicate the error.

Comment: To affirm what karen said, please put enough code in your question that we can cut and paste it into our own R sessions and be able to get the exact error that you did. Then we can code a solution and post it. Thanks :)